# How to prevent Angular element (web component) from overriding the style of its parent

Tags: css, angular, web-component

I have some issue with my Angular web component.
My angular application contains the web component as a child, but the issue is the css of the child component is also applying to its parent.

For instance, in web component, there's some style on its body tag. However, it is also overriding the style of its parent. Is there any way to avoid this?

```
<div id="my-app">
  <webcomponent></webcomponent>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you build your webcomponent? With angular elements?
Normally you can isolate styles in a web component by using shadow dom.

Comment: In Angular Elements you can set the ViewEncapsulation to ShadowDom: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Answer (score 2):

If you have built your webcomponent with Angular Elements, you can make use of dom / style isolation by setting `ViewEncapsulation` to `ShadowDom`:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "webcomponent",
  template: `
    <h3>Webcomponent</h3>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./webcomponent.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class WebcomponentComponent {}
```

Please notice that by using shadow dom, you will also not be able to style html inside the component from outside the component.

Answer (score 0):

I've used :host ::ng-deep successfully to achieve what you're looking for.

For the CSS inside web component, add :host ::ng-deep prior to your CSS element. Ex: `:host ::ng-deep .my-class { color: blue }`

From the docs, 'In order to scope the specified style to the current component and all its descendants, be sure to include the :host selector before ::ng-deep'

Docs: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep